# Repository GET returns JSON which contains both a content object and content array

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an entity with a ManyToOne relationship, when I use restTemplate.getForEntity(), the nested entity has its values wrapped in a `content` field at the same time there is a `content` array added overriding it

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@RestResource(exported = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "namespace", nullable = false)
private Namespace namespace;
```

A `GET` on the entity with this relation returns the following output body

```js
{
  "id" : "some_containing_id",
  "alertDefinition" : null,
  "namespace" : {
    "content" : {
      "id" : "some_namespace_id",
      "emailSenderName" : "some sender",
      "emailSenderId" : "foo@bar.com",
      "createdAt" : "2018-07-19T05:24:04.473Z",
      "updatedAt" : "2018-07-19T05:24:04.473Z"
    },
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  ...
```

So the namespace is being serialized containing 2 content fields with the array replacing the content object containing the values

SpringBoot 2.0.3.RELEASE

Namespace.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "namespace"
    , schema = "alert_notification"
)
public class Namespace implements java.io.Serializable {
    public transient static final String
        EMAIL_SENDER_NAME_DEFAULT = "some sender";
    public transient static final String
        EMAIL_SENDER_ID_DEFAULT = "foo@vbar.com";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "email_sender_name")
    private String emailSenderName = EMAIL_SENDER_NAME_DEFAULT;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "email_sender_id")
    private String emailSenderId = EMAIL_SENDER_ID_DEFAULT;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Well this is a problem, why is it producing a JSON response with 2 content fields? This isn't valid and doesn't work correctly

So be clear, because of this my response entity has all its values null

Comment: please post the content of your `Namespace`-class

Comment: Updated the original post including it

Comment: please provide a real example e.g. on github and post the link to it. otherwise it doesn't make any sense, because nothing is reproduceable using your posted source.

Comment: Well it is clearly happening given the response body and the reason for my post. This stems from a test failure.

Comment: yes, but there is no way to reproduce it with the information you provided

Comment: Why the down vote? It is a real problem and the reason I posted in the answer. Just because you can't reproduce it, if you are responsible to answer posts here, doesn't mean it isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the issue is caused by the `Hibernate5` module included in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5` which was recently introduced.

Interestingly enough the module doesn't even need to be enabled, having the dependency on the classpath alone will cause the problem.